# Unable to find Wkhtmltopdf on this system. The report will be shown in html

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, odoo-8

When I try to print report of any invoice this error pops up so i downloaded wkhtmltopdf from this link,http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html
After that in settings->system parameter I created a key called wkhtmltopdf and its value as C:\Program Files (x86)\wkhtmltopdf but still I am not able to print reports in pdf format as this error is not going. (I am on windows and this is the image)
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to set the key as `'webkit_path'` and also check the version of the `'wkhtmltopdf'`, it should `'0.12.2.1'`.
If you are using the config file to run Odoo, then try to provide a parameter `'bin_path'` and the value as the path to your `'wkhtmltopdf'` file.

Answer (score 3):

To install wkhtmltopdf in linux/unix operating system,

```
sudo wget https://downloads.wkhtmltopdf.org/0.12/0.12.1/wkhtmltox-0.12.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i wkhtmltox-0.12.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
sudo cp /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/bin
sudo cp /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage /usr/bin
```

Finally restart odoo server

Comment: Now the binaries are on github. So at this moment, try : sudo wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/packaging/releases/download/0.12.6-1/wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.buster_amd64.deb then sudo dpkg -i wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.buster_amd64.deb

Answer (score 2):

On Ubunutu 22.04

wget utility package

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install wget
```

wkhtmltopdf:

```
wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/packaging/releases/download/0.12.6.1-2/wkhtmltox_0.12.6.1-2.jammy_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i wkhtmltox_0.12.6.1-2.jammy_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get install -f
```

Answer (score 1):

On windows platform. Try to add the following parameter in .conf file of your odoo version.
bin_path = C:/Program Files/wkhtmltopdf/bin
Don't forget to restart your odoo afterwards.
It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

If some one is looking for the answer in ubuntu 20.04 then here is it:

```
wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/0.12.4/wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz
sudo dpkg -i wkhtmltox-0.12.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
```

If you get issue missing library `libpng12-0`:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/libpng12
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libpng12-0
```

If you get issue missing library `libssl1.0.0`:

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl1.0/libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.7_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.7_amd64.deb
```

then re-run this command:

```
sudo dpkg -i wkhtmltox-0.12.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
```

Hope this helped.